# i want to create new column in existing dataset of mobile numer last 5 degit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create new column in existing dataset column name is  mobile number I want to fetch last 5 digits of the mobile number column into the new column in python.

i tried wit this but its not getting ouput
mobile=data1[data1.Mobile_number.astype(str).str[5].eq('5')]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the mobile number column be text, you could use `str.extract` here:

```py
df["mobile"] = df["Mobile_number"].str.extract(r'(\d{5})$')
```

If the mobile number column be numeric, then use the modulus:

```py
df["mobile"] = df["Mobile_number"] % 100000
```

Comment: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: @AmitGajbhiye You never provided sample data.  Just use the remainder to find the last 5 digits in this case.